# Exit application when all forms hidden

Tags: c#, winforms

If you are building a windows forms application in C# and whenever the user opens a form from another form, the first form becomes hidden, how would you get the application quit if all forms were hidden?

I would have though of having instances of all the forms in a static class and have the application loop through the status of all the forms each time the user hides a form and if all are hidden then exit the application.  Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a good way to try to me. Give it a shot and let us know.

Answer (score 3):

Usually in this situation you would create a [`ApplicationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and you would pass that in to `Application.Run(` instead of a specific form.

If you look at the MSDN page for `ApplicationContext` it has a example of starting two forms then only closing the program when both forms get closed. You can make your own program use whatever logic you want, for example using hiding instead closing to trigger the `ExitThread()` call.